# Как упаковать класс c++/cli и передать как указатель в неуправляемый метод

Tags: c++, c++-cli

Можно ли, и как упаковать каким-то образом объект управляемый в указатель, и передать его в неуправляемый объект, что бы неуправляемый объект делал вызовы из этого указателя?

Comment: Можно. COM так работает. Я думаю вам нужен `Marshal.GetIDispatchForObject` - IDispatch интерфейс позволяет получить доступ практически к всем открытым членам. Почитайте функции из `Marshal` пространства, там есть и другие варианты связывания.

Comment: @nick_n_a: хм, интересно, сейчас пробую реализовать через auto_gcroot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В большинстве случаев достаточно неуправляемого класса `gcroot<...>`, который можно использовать *вместо* указателя. Считайте его разновидностью умного указателя.

В ситуации, когда нужен именно сырой указатель - можно использовать GCHandle.

Получение указателя:

```
GCHandle::ToIntPtr(GCHandle::Alloc(obj)).ToPointer()
```

Преобразование указателя обратно в объект:

```
GCHandle::FromIntPtr(gcnew IntPtr(ptr)).Target
```

Только не забудьте освободить GCHandle когда он перестанет быть нужен во избежание утечек памяти:

```
GCHandle::FromIntPtr(gcnew IntPtr(ptr)).Free()
```

Comment: Так не сработает пробовал, объект содержит данные которые нельзя преобразовать.

Comment: @Yami какой объект? Какие данные? Вы можете перестать говорить загадками?

Comment: Прошу прощения, сработало когда убрал GCHandleType

Comment: GCHandle.ToIntPtr, тоже не является настоящим указателем. Только GCHandle.AddOrPinnedObject для pinned handle возвращает реальный адрес (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2006/10/09/gchandle-tointptr-vs-gchandle-addrofpinnedobject/)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight сначала дайте определение понятию *"настоящий указатель"*.

Answer (score 0):

Решил таким способом:

Добавил неуправляемый класс помощник, в котором есть `map<int, gcroot<Object^>>`.
При записи в класс, сохраняем ссылку, и `HashCode` класса. Далее извлекаем класс из неуправляемого метода/кода, и в качестве параметра в коллбэке передаем наш хэш код, за счет этого вызываем и извлекаем именно нужный класс.

Вызовы происходят на ура! А так же вместо `System::Object^` может быть любой управляемый класс.

В итоге получаем такой класс:

```
#pragma once
#include <msclr\auto_gcroot.h>
#include <msclr\gcroot.h>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace msclr;

typedef std::map<int, gcroot<System::Object^>> mypack;

class vlc_helper
{
    vlc_helper();

    mypack m_map;

    static vlc_helper* m_instance_;
public:
    static vlc_helper& instance();

    ~vlc_helper();

    void release();
    gcroot<System::Object^> get_class(int id);
    void remove_data(int id);
    void add_data(int id, gcroot<System::Object^> ptr);

};
```

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "vlc_helper.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <cassert>

vlc_helper* vlc_helper::m_instance_ = nullptr;

vlc_helper::vlc_helper()
{
    m_map = mypack();
}

vlc_helper::~vlc_helper()
{
    m_map.clear();
}

vlc_helper &vlc_helper::instance()
{
    if (!m_instance_)
    {
        m_instance_ = new vlc_helper();
    }

    return *m_instance_;
}

void vlc_helper::release()
{
    delete m_instance_;
}

gcroot<System::Object^> vlc_helper::get_class(int id)
{
    mypack::iterator data = m_map.find(id);
    return data != m_map.end() ? data->second : nullptr;
}

void vlc_helper::remove_data(int id)
{
    mypack::iterator data;
    m_map.erase(id);
}

void vlc_helper::add_data(int id, gcroot<System::Object^> ptr)
{
    m_map.insert(std::make_pair(id, ptr));
}
```

Comment: А что вам помешало использовать непосредственно `gcroot<Object^>`? Зачем нужен map?

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Управляемый класс может иметь несколько инициализаций, и в коллбэк нельзя передать объект, или сущность, необходим указатель.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Если у вас есть другие идеи реализации, предложите их.

Comment: О каких колбеках речь? В вопросе их не было.

Comment: И какая разница сколько инициализаций у управляемого класса?

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Коллбэк это не так важно, важно то что необходимо было упаковать управляемый объект в указатель.

Comment: Вижу упаковку в int, не вижу у вас указателя.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ну костыль же =)

Comment: Просто на всякий случай: вы упаковываете класс не в указатель, а в "нечто похожее на указатель". Настоящие указатели для ссылочных типов не имеют смысла для в .NET, кроме как для объектов, явно "закрепленных" в памяти.